# Set display duration

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a HTML code, like

```
<button id="save" onclick="save_options()">Save</button>

<div id="status"></div>`
```

and a piece of javascript, like

```
function save_options() {
  var api = document.getElementById('wptk').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
    savedApi: api,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'OK! API Key saved!';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

After the button is clicked, in the `div id="status"` appears after 750 milliseconds a message `OK! API Key saved!`. Thats fine.

**But** the message is disappearing very fast! - how could i define the display duration of the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are clearing the status after 750 milliseconds.  Change it to 5 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 5000);
```

If you want to delay displaying the message, you will need to **set** the message after 750 milliseconds, set another timer, and then clear it.

```js
// Update status to let user know options were saved.
var status = document.getElementById('status');

setTimeout(function() {
  status.textContent = 'OK! API Key saved!';
  setTimeout(function() {
    status.textContent = ''
  }, 5000);
}, 750);
```

Comment: thanks! - thats it! i thought, setTimeout would be a time gap, AFTER which the message appears...